# Trouble creating frequency column from character column

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to add a column to a dataframe that gives the frequency of unique values in a character column. This is what I have so far:

```
              term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value
1      (Intercept) 6.0888310 1.3601938 4.4764437 8.318542e-06
2  factor(age76)25 0.6884056 0.8861507 0.7768494 4.374021e-01
3  factor(age76)26 0.2177806 0.9997128 0.2178431 8.275887e-01
4  factor(age76)27 0.5539639 0.9255542 0.5985213 5.496061e-01
5  factor(age76)28 0.8705031 0.5343690 1.6290300 1.035716e-01
6  factor(age76)29 1.2249185 0.7557118 1.6208804 1.053084e-01
7  factor(age76)30 0.6254308 0.8861507 0.7057838 4.804608e-01
8  factor(age76)31 1.2295179 0.5343690 2.3008782 2.157089e-02
9  factor(age76)32 0.3032523 0.8449115 0.3589161 7.197216e-01
10 factor(age76)33 1.1344686 0.7557118 1.5011921 1.335714e-01

sapply(df.b, class)
       term    estimate   std.error   statistic     p.value 
"character"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric" 

library(dplyr)

df.b$n <- group_by(df.b$term) %>%
  summarise(df.b$term, freq = n())

Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

There seems to be a problem with the character type of my column. When I change it to numeric I am under the impression that it will change to NA.

```
dput(head(df.b))
structure(list(term = c("(Intercept)", "factor(age76)25", "factor(age76)26", 
"factor(age76)27", "factor(age76)28", "factor(age76)29"), estimate = c(6.08883100125014, 
0.688405615000334, 0.21778058000053, 0.553963930000528, 0.870503050000005, 
1.22491850000015), std.error = c(1.36019381570938, 0.886150663575717, 
0.999712776013908, 0.925554182033106, 0.534368956146369, 0.75571182509336
), statistic = c(4.47644367363531, 0.776849404166263, 0.217843149778352, 
0.598521340785982, 1.62902998010529, 1.6208804193964), p.value = c(8.31854214736379e-06, 
0.437402143453174, 0.827588701982869, 0.549606122411782, 0.103571567056818, 
0.105308432290008)), .Names = c("term", "estimate", "std.error", 
"statistic", "p.value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have also tried this but it gives a warning code:

```
df.b$n <- group_by(df.b, term)%>%
  summarise(freq = n())
head(df.b)
             term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value                                                    n
1     (Intercept) 6.0888310 1.3601938 4.4764437 8.318542e-06                                    # A tibble: 6 x 2
2 factor(age76)25 0.6884056 0.8861507 0.7768494 4.374021e-01                                           term  freq
3 factor(age76)26 0.2177806 0.9997128 0.2178431 8.275887e-01                                          <chr> <int>
4 factor(age76)27 0.5539639 0.9255542 0.5985213 5.496061e-01 1                                  (Intercept)     1
5 factor(age76)28 0.8705031 0.5343690 1.6290300 1.035716e-01 2                              factor(age76)25     1
6 factor(age76)29 1.2249185 0.7557118 1.6208804 1.053084e-01 3               factor(age76)25:factor(black)1     1
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  Korrupter Data Frame: Spalten werden abgeschnitten oder mit NAs aufgefüllt
```

Comment: What's the `class()` and/or `str()` of `df.b`? If possible please share the result of `dput(head(df.b))` so we can try things out.

Comment: try: `group_by(df.b, term)` and check `?group_by`

Comment: @Phil: I added the output you asked for. I hope it is helpful. Meanwhile I am trying some other troubleshooting.

Comment: The warning code is caused by the fact you are trying to add a summary tibble as a column: try: `df %>%
  group_by(term) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) -> df`

Comment: @missuse: I just ran the following: `df.b$n <- group_by(df.b$term) %>%
+ mutate(n = n())`
`Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: If that is the output of a regression model then wouldn't all the observations be unique? And you are using `$` inside a `dplyr` pipe which is causing you the problem. Friendly advice: Learn some base R basics before jumping into packages. For what you need to do, with base R you can simply do `table(df.b$term)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the use of the key functions (`group_by` and `summarise`) in `dplyr`.

First of all, the output of these key functions is a data frame, not a vector. So you should not assign the output to `df.b$n`, a new column in the data frame.

Secondly, if you want to create a new column, use `mutate`. `summarise` it to summarise the group statistics, not to create a new column.

Thirdly, you may want to review how the pipe operation works (http://seananderson.ca/2014/09/13/dplyr-intro.html). The first argument of these key functions are all data frames. You should begin with `df.b2 <- df.b %>% group_by(...)` or `df.b2 <- group_by(df.b, ...)`, where `...` should be column names. In your original code, you use `group_by(df.b$term) %>%
  summarise(df.b$term, freq = n())` and leads to the error. This makes sense because `group_by` should take the first argument as a data frame, but you provided a character vector.

One final note, you may not show your entire data frame, but it seems like the elements in the `term` column are all unique, so the frequency count based on that column is probably all `1`. Make sure this is what you want.

I modified your code a little bit as follows. Hopefully, the output `df.b2` makes sense.

```
library(dplyr)

df.b2 <- df.b %>%
  group_by(term) %>%
  mutate(freq = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
df.b2
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#              term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value  freq
#             <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl> <int>
# 1     (Intercept) 6.0888310 1.3601938 4.4764437 8.318542e-06     1
# 2 factor(age76)25 0.6884056 0.8861507 0.7768494 4.374021e-01     1
# 3 factor(age76)26 0.2177806 0.9997128 0.2178431 8.275887e-01     1
# 4 factor(age76)27 0.5539639 0.9255542 0.5985213 5.496061e-01     1
# 5 factor(age76)28 0.8705031 0.5343690 1.6290300 1.035716e-01     1
# 6 factor(age76)29 1.2249185 0.7557118 1.6208804 1.053084e-01     1
```